# Load and dump to file in multithreading using Pickle and filelock - IOError: [Errno 13]

Tags: python, multithreading, pickle, filelock

I have a service that load and dump data from a python `dict` into a file using **python 2.7** `cPickle`. This service can be called simultaneously by many users.

What approach would allow `cPickle` to read and dump data into a single file in a multithreading context in order to avoid problems of desynchronization (loading while another process is dumping) of the data during operations?

I was thinking of using [filelock](https://github.com/benediktschmitt/py-filelock) but I havent been successful yet.

With my code below, the file is always have `cPickle.load(cache_file)IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied"` error in `init_cache()` or `update_cache()`

```
''' example of a dict dumped by pickle

  { 
     "version": "1499180895", 
     "queries": { 
         "001::id,name,age" : "aBase64EncodedString==",
         "002::id,name,sex" : "anotherBase64EncodedString=="
      }
   }

'''


import cPickle as pickle
import filelock
from os import path

self.cache_file_path = "\\\\serverDisk\\cache\\cache.pkl"
self.select_by_values = "001"
self.out_fields = ["id", "name", "age"]

def get_from_cache_fn(self):
    try:
        server_version = self.query_version()
        query_id = "{}::{}".format(self.select_by_values, ",".join(self.out_fields))
        if path.isfile(self.cache_file_path):
            cache_dict = self.load_cache(server_version, query_id)
            if cache_dict["version"] == server_version:
                if query_id in cache_dict["queries"]:
                     return cache_dict["queries"][query_id]
                else:
                    return self.update_cache(cache_dict, query_id)["queries"][query_id]
            else:
                return self.init_cache(server_version, query_id)["queries"][query_id]
        else:
            return self.init_cache(server_version, query_id)["queries"][query_id]
    except Exception:
        self.add_service_error(ERRORS["get_from_cache"][0], traceback.format_exc())


def load_cache(self, server_version, query_id):
    with open(self.cache_file_path, "rb") as cache_file:
        try:
            cache_dict = pickle.load(cache_file)
            return cache_dict
        except StandardError:
            return self.init_cache(server_version, query_id)


def init_cache(self, server_version, query_id):
    cache_dict = {
        "version" : server_version,
        "queries" : {
            query_id : base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(json.dumps(self.query_features())))
        }
    }
    lock = filelock.FileLock(self.cache_file_path)
    try:
        with lock.acquire(timeout=10):
            with open(self.cache_file_path, "wb") as cache_file:
                pickle.dump(cache_dict, cache_file)
                return cache_dict
    except lock.Timeout:
        self.add_service_error("init_cache timeout", traceback.format_exc())


def update_cache(self, cache_dict, query_id):
    cache_dict["queries"][query_id] = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(json.dumps(self.query_features())))
    lock = filelock.FileLock(self.cache_file_path)
    try:
        with lock.acquire(timeout = 10):
            with open(self.cache_file_path, "wb") as cache_file:
                pickle.dump(cache_dict, cache_file)
                return cache_dict
    except lock.Timeout:
        self.add_service_error("update_cache timeout", traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.

It appears that you have to give a different lock name than the file you are opening.

`lock = filelock.FileLock("{}.lock".format(self.cache_file_path))` instead of `lock = filelock.FileLock(self.cache_file_path)`

for instance:

```
def update_cache(self, cache_dict, query_id):
    cache_dict["queries"][query_id] = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(json.dumps(self.query_features())))
    lock = lock = filelock.FileLock("{}.lock".format(self.cache_file_path))
    try:
        with lock.acquire(timeout = 10):
            with open(self.cache_file_path, "wb") as cache_file:
                pickle.dump(cache_dict, cache_file)
                return cache_dict
    except lock.Timeout:
        self.add_service_error("update_cache timeout", traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Filelock documentation you should wrap the lock.acquire inside the `try{}except{}`. Otherwise it might just crash your app with unhandled exception when your acquire times out. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelock

Comment: thank you to point that out, but I still have the same error!

Comment: Maybe there is some bug in the library that lets 2 threads acquire the lock at the same time? I don't have any ideas what could be the problem.